# Using results from the loops for another one

Tags: java, math

I have to say sorry because I know that this is kind of a silly question (I just started learning java) but how can I use a "while" loop result for another loop? I need to prepare a program that will add digits from two given numbers. First of all I need to add digits from `number1` then `number2` and at the end sum digits of both. `sum1` and `sum2` are working pretty nice but its ending at this point, `sum3`, and operations in loop `nr3` are invisible for my machine.

I think I should combine it somehow into one loop but I got no idea how (I'm learning from Horstmann and Cadenhead books and there is no good answer)

Thank you for answer and I will be glad if it's not going to be a straight code upgrade but maybe some kind of hint where or what I should search! Thank You :) 
I have got something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int sum1 = 0;
    int sum2 = 0;
    int sum3 = 0;
    Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("1 : ");
    int l1 = scn.nextInt();
    System.out.println("2 : ");
    int l2 = scn.nextInt();
    System.out.println((0 > l1 || 0 > l2 ? "ERROR-NEGATIVE NUMBER" : "OK"));
    while (l1 > 0) {
        sum1 += l1 % 10;
        l1 /= 10;
    }
    //System.out.println(sum1);
    while (l2 > 0) {
        sum2 += l2 % 10;
        l2 /= 10;
    }
    //System.out.println(sum2);
    while (sum1+sum2>0) {
        sum3 +=(sum1+sum2) %10;
        (sum1+sum2) /=10;
    }

}
```

Comment: That last while loop should probably just `sum3 = sum1 + sum2;` (unless I'm missing something). Have you considered creating a single method to add the digits in an `int`?

Comment: This is just my opinion, but `int l1` ***should*** be an illegal variable name. That is far too easy to see as `11` or `ll`, better to use something else; if you want a short name use `t`, `i`, `j`, `a`, etc. Using two letters is fine, but at least pick something readable in combination (I can just imagine a larger program with `ll1` and `l11`, so please don't do that).

Comment: Thank You, names fixed- I appreciate every thing that will grow in my mind good programming practices :)

Comment: @AdamK Then you should also read about the Java Naming Conventions. They're introduced to help you keep your code clean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the main problem is that result of `/=` operator should be stored somewhere, result of sum1+sum2 does not provide such storage.

to make this code work, you need to store sum1+sum2 into some temp variable, so replace

```
while (sum1+sum2>0) {
    sum3 +=(sum1+sum2) %10;
    (sum1+sum2) /=10;
}
```

with something like:

```
int tempsum = sum1 + sum2;
while (tempsum > 0) {
    sum3 += tempsum % 10;
    tempsum /= 10;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

the best way is to use a method for that purpose and reuse it:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int sum3 = 0;
    Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("1 : ");
    int l1 = scn.nextInt();
    System.out.println("2 : ");
    int l2 = scn.nextInt();
    System.out.println((0 > l1 || 0 > l2 ? "ERROR-NEGATIVE NUMBER" : "OK"));
    sum3 = addDigit(addDigit(l1)+addDigit(l2))

}

private static int addDigit(int number){
    int sum = 0;
    while (number > 0) {
        sum += number % 10;
        number /= 10;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: `addDigit` Should be `static`, agree in principle though. Extra closing brace after `main`. Please fix indentation. `int sum = 0;` (typo).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch you are absolutely right! fixed it ;) thanks for your feedback